# Copying data files to output with Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, output

I've recently started to convert my former Windows-only app to other platforms, starting with Xamarin.iOS.
The code compiles, however I have some resource files located within "$ProjectDir/Data", which I want to copy to the output directory of the build, so that it can be accessed for example by "File.Load("Data/Database.db3")".
However, even though I have set the "Copy to output directory" to "Copy if newer", the "Data" folder for the app is created, however it remains empty.
Manually copying the files does work, however with every new build by Visual Studio for Mac, the Data folder is reset to empty.

Am I missing anything?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check you project bin folder to see which folder contains the newer files.  Depending on version of VS and option you are using not all the bin subfolders get updated.

Comment: I copied and pasted the folder location from the "FileNotFoundException" that I'm throwing to make sure I'm in the correct folder..

Comment: Copy to newer moves into the bin folder.  Open the csproj file with notepad and check if the folders are correct.